Difference between app and android in .xml file?
Today when i was working on one of my project when i had issue of white screen when we navigate from one screen to another screen. So i changed theme and added this line
 <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>

into my theme file so now it looks like this
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.Judgement" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>

after i have done this change my button backgroundtint is stopped working. i am giving background for radious in button but when i remove background than background tint is working but if i add that than not working why?
here is my button and background file both
button in xml file
       <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStartGame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/secondary"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="@string/start_game"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

here is my background file "round_btn.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10sp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/secondary" />
</shape>

i have tried to give color in background also it did not work as a poor entry level developer who doesn't have chat gpt 4 premium comes to the mother of all problems stackoverflow and here after some time i found answer of mr.Smirnov Sergey
and answer was lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button where he asks to change from android:backgroundTint to app:backgroundTint
so what is the difference between these? and please write in easy english and with context cause i am newbie here
and thank you so much in advance sorry if you got confused :)
I don't know what to write here please suggest me what to write here
